# What's the difference between iOS6 and iOS5 in loading a URL Video?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I've use `UIWebView`'s `loadRequest` method to load a URL Video from IP camera.
The test URL is http://kamera-zamek.jhcomp.cz/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480

In **iOS5** it works well, you can see the camera is moving in the video.
But in **iOS6**, video stops at the first frame.

For simple test, you can even copy the test URL to mobile Safari's address bar. It also behaves different in **iOS5** and **iOS6**. But in mac Safari, it works well.
So, what's the reason of this difference? How can I simply play the URL in iOS6 device?

I've linked the `QRCode` of the test URL, so you can just scan the `QRCode` and open in Safari.
[image: QRCode for the test URL]

Comment: In the case of Youtube videos, the URLs have changed when loading in iOS6.. here is the reference..https://devforums.apple.com/message/705665#705665.
In your case, the video is stored in your server or it is provided by someone else. if that is the case then check with them, have they changed the url to load for iOS6.

Comment: Hi, it's a URL of a Axis IP camera. It won't change for any other device.